# Git move local changes to another branch?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, `master` and `feature` and made local changes while being on `master`. Now I wanted to commit them into the `feature` branch but realized I am on the wrong branch `master`. `git checkout feature` does not work since it forces me to stash my changes, otherwise it will overwrite them.

My goal would be to checkout the `feature` branch and take the local changes with me. Can this be done? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: Stash your changes, switch the branch, unstash and commit.

Comment: On master do 'git stash'... Check out to feature branch then do git stash apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal flow would be:

```
git stash save "coming back"
git checkout -b some-feature develop # create feature branch from develop
git stash pop
```

Then you have your branch and your changes to continue working on.

Answer (score 1):

```
git add .                # this will move all local changes to staging area
git stash                # this will save your changes
git checkout -b feature  # this will create and checkout a new branch named feature 
git stash apply          # this will being all the stashed local changes
```

This way now you are in your feature branch will all your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `git checkout -m feature` to switch to the `feature` branch after attempting a three-way merge.  This may result in merge conflicts that should be resolved.

Comment: This is the best way, it accomplishes what the stash-switch-pop solution does except without extra gyrations.